# How to send push notifications with PFInstallation Query (Parse-Server)

Tags: swift, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to send a push notification with PFInstallation Query, that will send to the users that match the PFQuery. The Parse-server log shows that the notification sends but no one receives it. The `pushQuery` is constantly nil, although there are users that match the PFQuery. The code is as follows.

**CLOUD CODE**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("providerPush", function(request, response) {
    var expDate = new Date();
    expDate.setDate(expDate.getDate() + 1); 
    var data = {"badge": "Increment", "sound": "default"};
    data['alert'] = request.params.message;
    var userGeo = request.params.location;
    const providerQuery = new Parse.Query("ProvidersOnline");
    providerQuery.withinKilometers("location", userGeo, 2.5);
    providerQuery.equalTo("fulfilling", false);
    providerQuery.find();
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);    
    pushQuery.matchesQuery("username", providerQuery);
    pushQuery.find({useMasterKey: true }).then(function(results) {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(results);
        response.success(results);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(error);
        response.error(error);
    });
    Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
        data: data,
        expiration_time: expDate
    },{
        success: function () {
            response.success("Pushed successfully");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response.error(error);
        },
        useMasterKey: true
    });
});
```

**SWIFT CODE**

```
//SEND PUSH TO PROVIDERS
let orderQuery = PFQuery(className: "ProvidersOnline")
orderQuery.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: self.location, withinKilometers: 2.5)
orderQuery.whereKey("fulfilling", equalTo: false)

//orderQuery.order(byAscending: "createdAt")

orderQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: {(objects, error) -> Void in

    print("PROVIDER PUSH QUERY")
    print(objects?.count)
    print(error)

    if objects?.count != 0 && error == nil {

        print("PROVIDER PUSH SENT")

        if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {

                print("order query objects are")
                print(objects)
                print("order query done")

                let vehicle = object["location"] as! PFGeoPoint
                let distance: Double = self.location.distanceInKilometers(to: vehicle)
                let format = ".1"

                // Send push notification to query
                let pushMessage = "Someone requested a ride \(distance.format(format)) km away!"

                PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "providerPush", withParameters: ["message": pushMessage, "location": vehicle]) { (success, error) -> Void in

                    if error != nil {
                        print("error is not nil")
                        print(error!)
                    } else {
                        print("push success")
                        print(success!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you've got to enable client push somewhere? Might be a place to start looking!

Comment: @JakeT. Thank you. Client push is already enabled. Other remote push notifications are being sent, except this one with a query. I followed Parse's example but I don't understand the part                                 `pushQuery?.whereKey("username", matchesQuery: query)`

Comment: Do you have a `username` field on your `Installation` class? It wouldn't be there by default, you would have had to set that up. Also looking at your query more, within a loop you are making your push query run a query on the other one, which will push to all of the providers, instead of only the one that you've specifically validated to be within range or whatever.  If you do have a username field, you'd want to match it against object.get('username') instead of the whole `query` results.

Comment: @JakeT. thank you so much. Yes I've added the username field in my installation class, but it still says the objects are nil although it matches the query. On top of that, the debugger shows the error `Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection`. Finally, I am unclear as to what you mean by object.get('username') and where I would place that. I am trying to send the notification to all providers that are near the user's location.

Comment: Oh there's your answer. If you're going to do a find on an Installation query, it needs to be in your back end so you can use the master key.  Are you actually running the find, like in your commented out code? I would guess that you could trigger the push still, just not perform the query's find.

Comment: @JakeT. Thank you again. I tried following your instructions and use a cloud code function with useMasterKey in order to find on the installation query. However, I now get the error "Invalid type in JSON write (PFQuery)" I added the new code to the question.

Comment: I don't think that you can send a query object like that. `PFQuery` is an iOS class. You'll have to send parameters used to create the query.  If you want to make sure this works, just fill in some dummy data to make sure you get results / push you expect before sinking time into it.

Comment: @JakeT. Thank you so much I think we're super close to the working solution. I edited the code (both swift and cloud code) and the log says the pushes were successfully sent. However, they are not received by the providers, although they are able to receive all the other ones.

Comment: @JakeT. I found the solution, I used `matchesKeyInQuery(key, queryKey, query)`